# Mapbox automatic translation of street names

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I need to render English map of Russia with Mapbox GL JS, but I see hundreds/thousands of Russian streets in Mapbox are without proper English names (OSM rules are [against](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Names#Localization) transliteration).

Is there a way to use a custom transliteration function for "text-field" property in [Mapbox Style](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/)?

P.S.: "name:en" is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

1. map.queryRenderedFeatures and find all names.
2. Pass this through your transliteration function.
3. map.setPaintProperty setting the text-field with a case expression https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-case mapping Russian to English values.
4. Repeate 1 whenever the map view changes and data has loaded.

Comment: Is there a way how to pass a user function to setLayoutProperty()?

Answer (score -2):

You can localize your web map in three steps:

1. Start off with the “Display a map” example.
2. Reference the language plugin using the CDN or a module bundler.
3. Initialize the MapboxLanguageplugin and add it to your Mapobject.

[enter link description here](https://blog.mapbox.com/how-to-localize-your-maps-in-mapbox-gl-js-da4cc6749f47)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. This plugin just changes field from "name" to "name_*" according to target language. But there is not street names in Russia in Mapbox data. Just try to choose Russian language and check out the center of Saint-Petersburg, Russia. You'll see mix of Russian/English streets.